# Abort HTTP chunk encoded response with Error Page

Tags: http, chunked-encoding

I'm extending this previous question: [Aborting a HTTP/1.1 chunk encoded response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179750/aborting-a-http-1-1-chunk-encoded-response)

When I abort a chunked response Chrome displays a blank page and the dev console reports net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING. IE displays the incomplete page. Is there a way to send the user to an actual 500 error page?

Can I output something that corrupts the document so the browser won't use it? If so, what's the shortest string I can send to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no chunk you can send that says to the browser "Hey, forget everything I sent so far - something went wrong".  Sending a TCP reset packet will cause most browsers to display a "Server reset connection" page, but that requires access to one level down the network stack.

The only other I can think of is to try sending a chunk with a negative length.  I don't know how browsers react to that.

Comment: Is there any way to initiate a TCP reset through PHP? Maybe by calling an Apache function or exec or something?

Answer (score 0):

Here's something interesting I discovered. I'm not sure if it should be applied here, but for consideration:

The HTTP `Trailer` header might be a way to insert an invalidating header after the response.

> The Trailer general field value indicates that the given set of header
>   fields is present in the trailer of a message encoded with chunked
>   transfer coding.

Another consideration is the `Content-MD5` header. An aborted response won't validate. I'm not sure how browsers handle this.